# How to crawl the web content requires button click

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, web-crawler

I want to use Python to crawl app's version history from Apple Store, for instance: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/netflix/id363590051

To do so, I need to click on the **Version History** button in **What’s New** section. Below is the html of **Version History**, as you can see there is NO url link included:

```
<div class="version-history">
<button class="we-modal__show link section__nav__see-all-link" 
 id="modal-trigger-ember107103210" 
 data-metrics-click="{&quot;actionType&quot;:&quot;open&quot;,&quot;targetType&quot;:&quot;button&quot;,&quot;targetId&quot;:&quot;ModalVersionHistory&quot;}" 
 type="button">Version History</button>
<!----></div>
```

After clicking the Version History button, a new window containing version info appears within the same page, its html shows like:

```
<div id="modal-container"> ...version information... </div>
```

While previously this element was an empty:

```
<div id="modal-container"></div>
```

I think it is using [Bootstrap’s JavaScript modal plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/). But I have no idea about how to crawl the content requires button click and without url provided above. Could anyone give advice on how to implement this? I have Firefox selenium/requests installed in python. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Basically I find a solution. With Selenium, I can using element_to_be_clickable plus Xpath to find the button then click the button. The driver will return the content of the new page

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to show new content after click. 1. Its already loaded and in embedded in sourcecode. 2. A new request gets sended on click event. If its a new Request you can send the request for yourself. But on this page its option 1. So there is a  including this data as json.